# How do i link to a report(drill through) in another project?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two different reports created in two different projects. I would like to have a link back and forth between these two reports. Both the .RDL are uploaded in server and works fine. I know to link between the RDLs in the same project. But how do I handle this situation. Is that always good to have both the reports (rdl) in single project and do the link.  I would appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field you want to drill through from.  Go to Properties.  Go to the Navigation tab.  Choose the Jump to URL option and put something similar to the following expression in the textbox.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/reportserver?%2fpathto%2freport&rs:Command=Render&ProductCode="+Fields!ProductCode.Value+"'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  Are you passing a parameter between the reports, or are you just linking to it?  If you're just linking to it you could just copy the url for the report and add the link.  If you are passing a parameter to it it would be easier if they were in the same project.

i haven't read up on it or done anything with it yet, but i recently heard about [Report URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reports in Single project or if you want them in group-wise or to make them separate, you can also use multiple projects. The good example is given to link to another report which is in another project is given here. Please refer these links.

[sql-preview-a-subreport-which-is-in-another-ssrs-project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2010/12/21/sql-preview-a-subreport-which-is-in-another-ssrs-project.aspx)

--or--

[ssrs-jump-to-report-in-a-different-project](http://faultbucket.ca/2011/05/ssrs-jump-to-report-in-a-different-project/)